# Extracting year from a date string in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

The date in my data does not come in one single format. It comes as "yyyy", "mm/dd/yyyy" and "Jun-03". I want to extract the year out of it.

Answer (score 8):

Using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
In [24]: import dateutil.parser as parser

In [28]: parser.parse('Jun-03').year  # assumes the current year
Out[28]: 2013

In [29]: parser.parse('08/09/2012').year
Out[29]: 2012

In [30]: parser.parse('2012').year
Out[30]: 2012
```

Comment: I have installed the python-dateutil(2.1 version) but it would throw No module found. >>> import dateutil

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#101>", line 1, in <module>
    import dateutil
ImportError: No module named dateutil

Comment: How did you install `python-dateutil`? The message  `ImportError: No module named dateutil` indicates it was not successfully installed.

Comment: Downloaded the tar.zip file, unzipped it and from the command prompt went into the folder and typed 'python setup.py install' . I can see "python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg" folder only in the site packages

Comment: @mickey To install the package go to Scripts folder under Python folder and run the following:     `C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 3):

If you can assume that the year is always 4 digits except when the current year is implied, you can use a simple regular expression:

```
match = re.search('\d{4}', date)
year = match.group(0) if match else '2013'
```